# Get Selected radio button and hidden values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have dynamic radio buttons. I've to get the value of selected radio button and value of hidden input type bound to it. I'm having one input type as hidden to pass option id using

```
<input type="radio" name="sareefinishing" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="sareeOptionId" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>" />
```

Here is complete code:

```
  foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) {
        echo "Custom Option TITLE: <strong>" . $value->getTitle() . "</strong><br/>";

        $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($value);
        foreach($values as $opvalue){
            ?>
            <?php  echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>

            <input type="radio" name="sareefinishing" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sareeOptionId" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>" />

        <?php
        }
```

In my Javascript file I'm using following code

```
var data = $j('#customoption').serializeArray(); //customoption is form id
alert(data);
```

I'm getting correct selected label from radio button value from `<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>`but not it's corresponding value id from `<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>`. It gives all id values.

[image]

Comment: It will because each hidden input is unique element for the form whose value is not dependent on others which is not the case with the list of radio buttons

Comment: @TusharGupta: How I can get hidden value corresponding to the selected radio button?

Comment: google it use jquery or js your wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It will because each hidden input is unique element for the form whose value is not dependent on others which is not the case with the list of radio buttons.***

As far as I can understand, *you need the selected radio button's corresponding hidden value*; What you can do is

1. Create a single hidden field.
2. Create the Radio button with attribute:`data-sareeOptionId = <?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>`
3. On the change of radio button, fill the hidden field with the `data-sareeOptionId` of the radio button using javascript using on change event.
4. Serialize the form.

Code Flow : `Radio option` Like

```
<input type="radio" data-sareeOptionId="<?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>" name="sareefinishing" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `sareeOptionId` all as the same `name`

Make them a different `name` and it won't combine them into one value

Comment: but I'm getting only 1 and correct selected value from first input box.

Comment: Please explain what you are getting? There is no input box in your code

Comment: @amitshree becoz radio btn has same name and it select the selected one but this is not case with input field