# Get data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using below code to get data attribute values. But irrespective of my selected I'm getting only first value of foreach loop.

```
foreach($values as $opvalue){
            ?>
            <?php  echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>
            <?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>
            <input type="radio" data-sareeid="<?php echo $opvalue->getId(); ?>" id ="sareefinishing" name="sareefinishing" value="<?php echo $opvalue->getTitle(); ?>" />

        <?php
        }
```

JavaScript code:

```
var sareeOption = document.getElementById('sareefinishing');
    alert(sareeOption.dataset.sareeid);
```

From below picture, it always alerts 61818.
Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665304/get-selected-radio-button-and-hidden-values)
[image]

Comment: can you paste the rendered html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id should be unique in your code, otherwise it will always choose first one. So yo need to use class. You were tagged jQuery so do something like this using **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
var sareeOption = $('.sareefinishing:checked');
alert(sareeOption.data('sareeid'));
```

Answer (score 2):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onaodvo4/)

```
$("input[name=qwe]").change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert($(this).val())
}
})
```

You can do it like this, use name then for change in radio button get the value then alert it

Answer (score 2):

You can't have duplicate ids in any given document. Hence, use classes. Here is a pure javascript solution.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.sareefinishing');
[].forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener("change", function() {
      alert (this.dataset.sareeid);
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="sareefinishing" data-sareeid="10" name="sareefinishing" value="10" />
<input type="radio" class="sareefinishing" data-sareeid="20" name="sareefinishing" value="20" />
<input type="radio" class="sareefinishing" data-sareeid="30" name="sareefinishing" value="30" />
<input type="radio" class="sareefinishing" data-sareeid="40" name="sareefinishing" value="40" />
```

[**Another demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vuf7qmgp/1/) where it shows the selected radio button's `sareeid` on a button click.